# How to tune your guitar to F major on capo 5?

Tags: alternative-tunings

So i'm learning how to play yesterday by Beatles on my acoustic guitar and I have self taught myself so I have no tuning knowledge about the guitar whatsoever. So when watching this video about how to play this song I encountered one video where the guy said to tune your guitar to a f major chord on capo 5. How do i do this? I'm using a guitar tuner on my phone.

Answer (score 4):

He is playing a C shape chord for the F chord with the capo on 5th fret is my guess. Why do that? It's just to avoid playing the F barre chord at 1st fret. Keep your guitar in standard tuning. The song is played with standard tuning and traditional chords. Watch other videos for examples.

Answer (score 1):

If he stated 'tune your guitar to an F major chord on fret 5', then it's not accurate. He means tune your guitar normally, then when you put a capo on fret 5 and finger a C shape, it'll produce an F chord. It's minimally easier than other ways, but still needs a Bb chord later, which requires an F shape chord there!